# Pass an object as parameter then extend and return this object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to 'extend' a function in TypeScript, but i'm not finding the right way.

```
const fn1 = function () {
  return {
    extend(obj1: { [name: string]: Function }) {
      return {
        test1() {},
        ...obj1
      }
    }
  }
}
const var1 = fn1().extend({ test2: function () {} });

var1.test1()
var1.test2() // Property 'test2' does not exist on type '{ test1(): void; }'. Did you mean 'test1'?
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be enough to add a generic type to `extend`.

```
const fn1 = function () {
  return {
    extend<F extends Record<string, Function>>(obj1: F) {
      return {
        test1() {},
        ...obj1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`F` will store the type of the object passed to the function. The compiler is smart enough to compute the correct return type so we don't have to provide one.

```
const var1 = fn1().extend({ test2: function () {} });
//    ^? const var1: { test1(): void; } & { test2: () => void; }

var1.test1()
var1.test2()
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvPArmYUCW4YAUAlDAN4BQMMATgKZTrVhmVUy0AeUtYAJgDwAxdlx68IMAEq1Q1AdGo4wAcwA0MQZmx4wAPl0EQAIwBWiAFwaSFNmzoMmLW7e7RExMgF9VrZzAB0gcZmvmyeoeFU4eHkoJCwAG4AhtTIaAjuRP6c3HwEpDCuUABMlnBauPgepJ4wnkQA3OQA9M22AHoA-DBx0DDJqZYFRZmWCSA4vA11MABkZIW00KWEJCi6-RNTdeTkA4j+I8R7KQdFxcRAA)

Comment: `F extends { [name: string]: Function }` would have worked too. It highlights how this was just a matter of using generics

Comment: Is there an easy way to use ```this``` inside extend after I called it? I have access to ```this.test1()``` inside ```.extend({ ... })``` but TypeScript says that I don't.

Comment: Answering my own comment, I found a way to do it `extend<F extends { [name: string]: Function }>(obj1: F & ThisType<F & { test1: () => void }>) {`. It's not very pretty, especialy if I have a lot of functions, but I did not find a better way.